# Generic methods for serializing and deserialzing xml files using streams

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Common.Extensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains the logic for streaming extensions.
    /// </summary>
    public static class StreamExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize an object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object that gets serialized.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="stream">The stream to which the bytes will be written.</param>
        /// <param name="serializableObject">The object that gets serialized.</param>
        public static void SerializeObject<T>(this Stream stream, T serializableObject) where T : IXmlSerializable
        {
            var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();

            writerSettings.Indent = true;
            writerSettings.IndentChars = "    "; // 4 spaces
            writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, writerSettings))
            {
                serializableObject.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
            }

            stream.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserialize a stream and return the object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object that returns from the deserialization.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="stream">The stream which contains the bytes to deserialize.</param>
        /// <returns>The object recovered.</returns>
        public static T DeserializeObject<T>(this Stream stream) where T : IXmlSerializable
        {
            using (var xmlTextReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                T result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
                stream.Close();
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have made a class which can serialize a generic object which implements the interface `IXmlSerializable` and can deserialize an xml file to that same object. The idea behind this is as follows: we are using a lot of xml files to (for example) write configurations to. Since the configuration classes are often different we needed a generic function to create and read the xml files.

The stream we use (atm) is a file stream since it is currently only used for reading and writing the xml files to and from disk. Later we might use other kind of streams as well.

I am wondering if what I have written is the correct way (obviously it works but can it be made better? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> writerSettings.IndentChars = "    "; // 4 spaces
> ```

by using

```
writerSettings.IndentChars = string.Empty.PadRight(4, ' ');
```

you wouldn't need that noisy comment.

---

One wouldn't expect that a passed in `Stream` get closed inside that method. The closing of a `Stream` should only belong to the creator of that stream.

---

In extension methods you should always check the argument which is reffered by `this` if it is `null`.
This is because that method can also be called like so

```
StreamExtensions.SerializeObject<someType>(null, someObject);
```

By checking `(stream == null)` and throwing an `ArgumentNullException` no unnecessary objects like `XmlWriterSettings` will be created.

---

Otherwise than the mentioned points your code looks clean and is easy to read.

Comment: +1 for "The closing of a Stream should only belong to the creator of that stream."

Comment: Yes I agree on all points, only (as a development team) we decided to close the stream inside this method. Should it really not be done? Perhaps add a line in the summary of the method that the stream will be closed?

Comment: Maybe you(the team) should think about it again. In addition you should always assume that a `public` method will be used by someone else too. Having a line in the summary can be missed if it doesn't match with what one will expect.

Comment: Oke, we will re-discuss it, thanks for all the points :)

Comment: There's another _better_ alternative alternative `new string(' ', 4)` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

@Heslacher already mentioned the important stuff. One other change would be to use [object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx). I also don't see any issue with making it a `private static readonly` variable to avoid instantiating it every time the method is called.

> ```
>       var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
>       writerSettings.Indent = true;
>       writerSettings.IndentChars = "    "; // 4 spaces
>       writerSettings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
> ```

```
        private static readonly XmlWriterSettings _writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Indent = true,
            IndentChars = "    ",
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
        };
```